# #NAME? in every textbox of Access 2016 Form, SQL Server linked table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an access form with a fairly complex query displaying raw test values and the resulting test calculations on a large MS Access Form that was created in access 2007. Every once in a while my data entry guys are complaining that upon leaving and returning to their database form they see an error with text "This expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements...". After this error appears every textbox is populated with the "#NAME?" error code.

I am curious if anyone has experience with this. I recently migrated the backend table from another MS Access database to SQL Server. My table has a primary key in SQL Server and also a timestamp column. Lastly, I have tried to reduce the size of the query that produces the calculations displayed on the form. On top of that not working, it previously worked  *within Access* , so I don't see how simply moving the table to SQL server would cause the size of the query to now be too much.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but I've recently experienced a similar issue and found it to be data type related.

Check if your SQL Server table's primary key data type is "bigint". If it is this may cause problems reading the data in Access.  Access 2016 supports large number types but it needs to be set in Options-->Current Database-->Data Type Support Options. Note that setting large number support will prevent your Access app from working in version prior to 2016.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem but I had to enable bigint support *before* linking the table.

Comment: Excellent, Mike. I keep a copy of Access 2010 for front ends against SQL Server, using the much maligned ADP. Works very well for us but we do all the development through SSMS, ADP file strictly for data entry and reads.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, which may actually speed up the forms as well. Is to rewrite the query you are using as your bound data source for the form as a view on the SQL server.

Then link this view to your MS Access front end and use it as the bound object.

Depending on your requirements, Read/Write, and experience in SQL this may be an easy thing to do or a moderately tough thing to do.

Access is pretty greedy with the network connection so any processing you can move server side is fantastic.